# Sort JSONs by IP Network in python3

Tags: python, json, sorting, ip

I would like to sort these JSON objects by the key "vnet" in each range (eg. range1, range2) in python3.

I have been able to sort it like this:

```py
source["range1"].sort(key=lambda x: x["vnet"])
```

But unfortunately it does not use any IP address logic and sorts it by char.

Unsorted example:

```json
{
    "range1": [
        {
            "name": "vnet1",
            "vnet": "192.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet2",
            "vnet": "192.168.2.0/24",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ],
    "range2": [
        {
            "name": "vnet3",
            "vnet": "10.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet4",
            "vnet": "10.168.2.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet5",
            "vnet": "10.168.220.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Sorted it should look like:

```json
{
    "range1": [
        {
            "name": "vnet2",
            "vnet": "192.168.2.0/24",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet1",
            "vnet": "192.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ],
    "range2": [
        {
            "name": "vnet4",
            "vnet": "10.168.2.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet3",
            "vnet": "10.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet5",
            "vnet": "10.168.220.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I would very much appreciate any help on this, since I am stuck here right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your dict stored in `json_dict`.

You can use `socket.inet_aton(__ip_string: str)` as a key to sorting function. It will convert ip string to 32-bit packed binary.

So the following code will do what you want

```
import socket

json_dict = {
    "range1": [
        {
            "name": "vnet1",
            "vnet": "192.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet2",
            "vnet": "192.168.2.0/24",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ],
    "range2": [
        {
            "name": "vnet3",
            "vnet": "10.168.11.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet4",
            "vnet": "10.168.2.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        },
        {
            "name": "vnet5",
            "vnet": "10.168.220.0/25",
            "subnet": []
        }
    ]
}

for key, value in json_dict.items():
    value.sort(key=lambda x: socket.inet_aton(x['vnet'].split("/")[0]))

print(json_dict)
```